# accessing a controller (method) from a model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm having trouble accessing a method from a model.

I have tried doing the following:

```
$CI= & get_instance();      
$array = $CI->buildDateArray($this->session->userdata('dates'), $dateFormat);
```

but it doesn't go into that method.

Please advise,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure (read: about 80%) that CI doesn't do HMVC, so you can't make requests to controllers from your model.

I'd have a good hard look at the flow of your application, because **normally** you shouldn't be doing that (normally). If you really need to, consider http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Modular_Extensions_-_HMVC - not sure if it's any good, but it looks like it should do the job.

Bonus points if you decide to switch to Kohana or Fuel for your app, they're harder to pick up, but more powerful :P

Comment: Thanks @Joe, I came right but probably a bit of a hack... :( but will definitely checkout Kohana. Unfortunately the whole app is based on CI and would be impossible to rewrite everything to a new MVC...and the more I work with CI the more I pick up it's limitations and lack of proper functionality.